# Raspberry pi receives numbers from arduino

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am experimenting with connecting Raspberry Pi to Arduino, and when I set a loop to receive info from Arduino Uno serial, it only receives:

```
'118537\r\n'
```

That is when I try to serial print 'Hi'

Here is my arduino code:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.println('Hi');
  delay(2000);
}
```

Here is my python 3.2 code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
while True:
    print(ser.readline())
```

This prints: '118537\r\n' every 2 seconds.

How can I get the original 'Hi' every 2 seconds?

Comment: Are you sure it's `attyACM0`  ot `ttyACM0`??

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you who want to know, it was the fact that I used ' instead of " in the string, changing:

```
Serial.println('Hi');
```

to

```
Serial.println("Hi");
```

---

**eta:** the reason why '118537\n\n' is printed out is because `'Hi'` is a literal array of two `bytes` rather than a *"string"* and therefore the *compiler* uses the function for printing an `int`. In fact, the `hex` code of `H` is `48` and the `hex` code of `i` is `69`, and the *hexadecimal value* of `0x4869` is exactly `118537` in decimal notation.